# format integer as chars in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

What's the best way to format output a integer as char sequences? I try below code block, it works but not sure if it's right to do it:

```
(defun int2chars(x)
  (format t "~c~c~c~c~%"
      (code-char (ldb (byte 8 24) x))
      (code-char (ldb (byte 8 16) x))
      (code-char (ldb (byte 8 8) x))
      (code-char (ldb (byte 8 0) x))
      ))

(defun test()
  (let ((x #x75756964))
    (int2chars x)))

(test)
```

Input is `0x75756964` and output is `uuid`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a function that works for integers that are larger or shorter than 32 bits:

```
(defun bytes-from-integer (integer)
  (check-type integer (integer 0))
  (loop
    with size = (* 8 (1- (ceiling (integer-length integer) 8)))
    for offset from size downto 0 by 8
    collect (ldb (byte 8 offset) integer)))

(bytes-from-integer #x75756964)
=> (117 117 105 100)

(bytes-from-integer #x7575696475756964)
=> (117 117 105 100 117 117 105 100)
```

Then, you convert to a string as follows:

```
(map 'string #'code-char (bytes-from-integer #x75756964))
=> "uuid"
```

---

Note: [`CHECK-TYPE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_check_.htm) is a macro that checks whether a *place* satisfies a given *type* expression. Above, the place is the `integer` variable, and the type is [`(integer 0)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_intege.htm), which is equivalent to `(integer 0 *)`, also known as `unsigned-byte`.

Comment: Thanks, I am confused with `(check-type integer (integer 0))`, sounds like `integer` is not a function but used as a function?

Comment: @lucky1928 I edited the answer to add some remarks about check-type